# Types are not getting resolved when using DefaultSignatures

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am struggling with `default` definition for a range of instances. GHC does not resolve types for some reason.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}

module Main where

import           Control.Monad.State.Strict (liftIO)
import qualified Data.Aeson                 as JSON
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as B
import           Data.Maybe
import           GHC.Generics               (Generic)

dataDir :: FilePath
dataDir = "data/"

class LoadFromFile a where
  loadFromFile :: FilePath -> IO a
  default loadFromFile :: JSON.FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO a
  loadFromFile filename = fmap (fromJust . JSON.decode) $ B.readFile ( dataDir ++ filename )

requirementsHistoryFile :: FilePath
requirementsHistoryFile = "requirementsHistory.json"

data Requirement = Contains String deriving (Show, LoadFromFile, JSON.FromJSON, Generic)
type RequirementsHistory = [Requirement]

displayRequirementsHistory :: RequirementsHistory -> IO ()
displayRequirementsHistory requirementsHistory = mapM_ (putStrLn . show) requirementsHistory

main :: IO ()
main = do
  requirementsHistory <- liftIO $ loadFromFile requirementsHistoryFile
  displayRequirementsHistory requirementsHistory
```

Getting following error, not really clear why:

```
Main.hs:31:35: error:
    • No instance for (LoadFromFile RequirementsHistory)
        arising from a use of ‘loadFromFile’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘loadFromFile requirementsHistoryFile’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        requirementsHistory <- liftIO
                                 $ loadFromFile requirementsHistoryFile
      In the expression:
        do requirementsHistory <- liftIO
                                    $ loadFromFile requirementsHistoryFile
           displayRequirementsHistory requirementsHistory
   |
31 |   requirementsHistory <- liftIO $ loadFromFile requirementsHistoryFile
   |
```

Any ideas why this error might be occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `deriving` clause produces an instance `LoadFromFile Requirement` but you need `LoadFromFile RequirementsHistory` ie. `LoadFromFile [Requirement]`. I believe your default signature will allow defining this with merely:

```
instance LoadFromFile RequirementsHistory
```

Alternatively, you could define a more general instance like:

```
instance JSON.FromJSON a => LoadFromFile a
```

This will probably get you into trouble with overlapping instances.

Answer (score 1):

The default signature always comes only into play if you *have* an `instance` declaration, but don't choose to define the method. So in your case, you'd need to write simply

```
instance LoadFromFile RequirementsHistory
```

(notice there's no `where` part needed), plus any `LANGUAGE` extensions that GHC asks you to enable.